# Arrange points such that translates of orthants separate subsets of them

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, discrete-mathematics, discrete-geometry

Is it possible to arrange $n$ distinct points $A = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \subseteq \mathbb R^k$
so that every subset $B \subseteq A$ could be written as
$$
 (y_B + \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^k) \cap A
$$
for some point $y_B \in \mathbb R^k$, i.e., $B = (y_B + \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^k) \cap A$. In some sense this means that the translates of the orthants $y_B + \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^k$ separate all subsets of $A$.

Is this possible if $k < n$?

If $k = n$ (or more generally $k \ge n$) this is possible. Let us denote the $j$-the coordinate of some point $x$ by $\pi_j(x)$, for example $\pi_2((1,2,3)) = 2$.
Now let $A = \{x_1, \ldots, x_{n-1}\}$
be some such arrangement in $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. Then we can 
embed this into $\mathbb R^{n-1} \times\{0\} \subseteq \mathbb R^n$, hence we suppose the $n$-coordinate of the $x_i$ is zero, and also of the $2^{n-1}$ points $y_B$ for $B \subseteq A$ too. 
Let $x := \max_{B\subseteq A} \max_{j=1,\ldots,n-1} \pi_j(y_B)$.
Set $x_n = (x,\ldots,x,-1)$.
Then $x \notin y_B + \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^n$ for all $B \subseteq A$. Now consider
$y_{B \cup \{x_n\}} := (\pi_1(y_B), \ldots, \pi_{n-1}(y_B), -1)$,
we have
$$
 (y_{B\cup \{x_n\}} + \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^n) \cap (A \cup \{x_n\}) = B \cup \{x_n\}.
$$
Noting that for $n = 1$ everything is trivial so we can inductively find such an arrangement of $n$ points in $\mathbb R^n$.

I somehow think it is not possible if $k < n$ (for example you cannot do it if $k = 1$). But I do not have an argument for this...

Comment: I would not call $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}^k$ a half-space. It is more like a $(1/2)^k$-space. The best terms is orthant.

Comment: @MikeEarnest Yes, thank you. I changed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will call a set $A=\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ *separable* if your property holds, i.e. $\forall B \subset A, \exists\  y_B \in \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $B = (y_B + \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^k) \cap A.$

Let $\pi_j(v)$ denote the $j$th coordinate of $v$ as you suggested.

**Definition:** Coordinate $j$ is *separating* for point $x_i$ if $\pi_j(x_i) < \pi_j(x_k) \ \forall k \neq i,$ i.e. if $x_i$ has the strictly minimum $j$th-coordinate value among all points.

**Claim 1:** $A$ is separable $\implies$ every $x \in A$ has some separating coordinate, i.e.:

$$\forall i, \exists j \text{   such that   } \pi_j(x_i) < \pi_j(x_k) \ \forall k \neq i.$$

**Proof:** Consider subsets of the form $B = A - \{x_i\}$.  By assumption, $A$ is separable so $y_B$ exists.  Now $x_i \notin B \implies x_i \notin (y_B + \mathbb R_{\ge 0}^k) \implies$ there exists some coordinate $j$ s.t. $\pi_j(x_i) < \pi_j(y_B)$.  But all other $x_k \in B$, which means $\pi_j(y_B) \le \pi_j(x_k)$.  Combining, we have $\pi_j(x_i) < \pi_j(x_k)$ strictly.

**Corrollary:** $n > k$ is impossible, because there are only $k$ coordinates and so $n$ points cannot each have its own separating coordinate. (Clearly two points cannot have the same $j$ as separating coordinate, since ties are not allowed.)

---

In fact, the converse of Claim 1 is also true, i.e.

**Claim 2:** $A$ is separable $\iff$ every $x \in A$ has some separating coordinate.

**Proof:** We only need to prove the $\Leftarrow$ direction, and we will do so by constructing $y_B$ explicitly.  For any $B\subset A$, consider any $x_i \notin B$ and suppose it is separating in coordinate $j$.  Pick $\pi_j(y_B) = \min_{k \neq i} \pi_j(x_k),$ i.e. the second-minimum value.  This choice would exclude $x_i$ and no other point.  We can do this for every $x_i \notin B$ because they all have different separating coordinates.  Finally, in all other coordinates pick $\pi_j(y_B) = \min_{k} \pi_j(x_k),$ i.e. the minimum value so as to include all points.  Thus, every point $\in B$ has all its coordinates $\ge y_B$ while every point $\notin B$ has its separating coordinate $< y_B$.

**Example:** For $n=k$, let $\pi_j(x_i) = -1$ if $i=j$ and $=0$ if $i \neq j$.  For every $B$, simply set $\pi_j(y_B) = -1$ if $x_j \in B$ and $=0$ if $x_j \notin B$.  Thus we have an explicit construction which does not rely on proof by induction.